# Illegal modifier for parameter [frmStartupGame]; only final is permitted

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm new to java and i trying to do an appointement for school in Java.
It's a small game that follow the MVC model (I don't know how it's suppose to work, all i understand is this method separate code in "package" so we just need to modify some element in some package to, for example, make the game look totaly different; is that right?).

So we created a startup frame using the JFrame and JPanel package.
Now it's time for me to create the main() method in a class name "Control" in the controller package:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package controller;

public class Control {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();  
    }
}
```

Now my teacher ask me to: "Declare in private the property frmStartupGame of type StartupGame (the name of the first fram we created earlier) and add the package "view" witch contain our StartupGame file.

I don't really understand what's going on and what my teacher ask me...

I think he want me to create a link between the two file (By importing the "view" package in the control class?) and so the first element to start will be in the main in controller.
In order to do that, we need to declare a StartupGame instance in the Control File, Right?

So i tried to do that

```
/**
 * 
 */
package controller;

import view.StartupGame;

public class Control {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
        private StartupGame frmStartupGame;
    }
}
```

But now i have a "Illegal modifier for parameter [frmStartupGame]; only final is permitted" error; i can't find the correct syntax to declare the instance of StartupGame in the Control Class...

Comment: Variables placed inside of the methods (`main` in ur case) can't have any access modifiers (`private`, `public` and so on). You probably was meant to declare it inside of the class but outside of any method.

Comment: You might want to read up on [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) then. It boils down to a separation of concerns. Part of your code should only be about the core logic (and not care how the output will be generated or how the input will be gathered), that's the _model_. Another part of your code should only concern itself with displaying stuff on screen, that's the _view_. A third part should gather user input and act as middle-man between the other parts, that's the _controller_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its means inside function only final is allowed:

So below code in not valid:

```
 private StartupGame frmStartupGame;
```

Change that to:

```
 StartupGame frmStartupGame;
```

**Update:** "Now my teacher ask me to: "Declare in private the property frmStartupGame of type StartupGame"

Create this variable on class level like below:

```
public class Control {
    private StartupGame frmStartupGame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();  
    }
}
```

See [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) for more details

Comment: As far as I understand OP was asked to declare it as private field so it should be moved outside of the method.